# Universal app - iPad view loads, but I cannot link any Image Views to the UIImage objects without getting an error

Tags: xcode, ios, ipad

I have a simple universal app I am working on, basically there are 10 images and 10 buttons on the screen.  If you click button2, then image2 will disappear, click button2 again and image2 will reappear.  My iphone version works perfectly, but I'm having issues with the iPad.

I have the app load MainWindow-iPad.xib, which gets its view from AppNameViewController-iPad.xib.  I also have AppNameViewController-iPad.h/.m which has the methods and UIImage objects needed.

Now, if I have nothing linked, I can see the iPad view perfectly.  If I link a button with its corresponding method, the view will still load.  If I link an Image View with the corresponding UIImage (IE link image2.png with UIImage *image2) and try to run the program, I get this error in the debug field:

> 2011-04-12 12:46:45.400 AppName[14106:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image2.'

Xcode then brings me to main.m and gives an error at this line:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); //THIS LINE HERE
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

The error says "Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGABRT".

I'm not sure if it matters, but I have one AppDelegate.h/m for the whole app but a separate ViewController.h/m for iPhone and iPad.  I have a feeling I just didn't link something right with my xibs, but I'm a very new developer and I just haven't been able to figure it out.  Many thanks if somebody can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it will help you, but I got exactly the same error message in my first attempt to build a universal app. I did not do any linking, so the root cause could be different.

I'm running Xcode 4, and under your target you can choose your Main Interface. If I choose AppNameViewController I get your problem. If I choose MainWindow it works fine.

I'm far from an expert on this thing, but it could maybe lead you to the right answer...

Why cant Apple give some more universal app tutorials?

Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, I got it working and posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go through "Your first iOS Application" on the Apple developer website and it went through the correct way to set up your view controller. I just used those steps twice, once on the iPhone view controller and once on the iPad's. Check it out if you want some help:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514